# Probem with formatting fields

Tags: entities

Two questions that I guess are both a part of one bigger idea. When creating a content type, I've been trying to figure out how to both indent a field and create a line break after a field both by default. For indenting I have tried adding spaces before the field name, but because it's empty space they are disregarded and displayed as normal. For the line break, I've tried adding a custom code field with br or p, and simply adding a blank field, but in both situations as there is no text to display, the field is not displayed at all. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest thing to do is to use the [`#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) Form Control Attribute. You can specify a CSS class to target this element to then supply some css rules to indent these elements in your sites theme.

Similarly, you can add a class to add a line break somewhere within the widget markup to create your linebreak. Be sure to notice that the class example in the linked documentation takes a PHP array of class(es) (not a string label for the class) ... that messed me up last week for like 20 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only problem is...I am new to both Drupal and to CSS, and have little to no understanding of how to do any of this. I know that it would be best for me to go and learn CSS before tackling Drupal, but this is just the situation I ended up in. So, if you are willing to keep helping me out, what would be the best way to add this CSS, and how would I use it specifically on a designated field? I have installed Display Suite, and noticed that there is a "styles" area within it. Would this be the place to go to apply the CSS?